# moving focus on selecting value from aoutocomplete menue using mouse click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have the below mentioned code which validates whether the user had entered data which is only available in the autocomplete menu and if its valid then it will move to the next textbox.

```
$("#Text1").autocomplete({ source: function(req, responseFn) { 
  var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);         
  var textinput = new RegExp( "" +re, "i" );      
  var match = $.grep( crtfdesc, function(item,index){           
  return textinput.test(item);         
  });       
  responseFn( match ); 
  }, 
  change: function(event, ui){var flag;
    var cval=$(this).val();
    var len=crtfdesc.length;

    for(var c=0;c<len;c++)
    {
        if(cval==crtfdesc[c]){ flag=1;$("#text2").focus();break;}
        else
        { flag=2;}
    }
 if(flag==2){$(this).val("");}

  },
  select: function(event, ui){
        $("#text2").focus(); 
  }
});//Text1
```

but this code is not working if i select a value using mouse click. The focus remains on the autocomplete textbox.

Comment: The code is working fine. The only change that i made is i moved from jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.2 to jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.11 and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working fine. The only change that i made is i moved from jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.2 to jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.11 and the problem is solved.